# Container doesn't work on the whole content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am building a webpage using Twitter Bootstrap. I have a `.box` class where I put my content. The problem is, that on one of the pages where I have 2 boxes, one of them doesn't have the proper width of the container. The first box is wider than the second one and It doesn't look nice. I think that there will be a problem with an unclosed div or something like that, but I wasn't able to figure that out.

**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>MG STAV - Reference</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">    

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/business-casual.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="css/bootstrap-lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab:100,300,400,600,700,100italic,300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container text-center">
      <img class="img-responsive brand-img" src="img/logo.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <!-- navbar-brand is hidden on larger screens, but visible when the menu is collapsed -->
                <a class="navbar-brand" id="link" href="index.html">MG STAV stavební, spol. s r.o</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a id="link" href="index.html">Domů</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a id="link" href="about.html">O společnosti</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a id="link" href="reference.html">Reference</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a id="link" href="contact.html">Kontakt</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="box"> 
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <hr>
                    <h2 class="intro-text text-center">Naše
                        <strong>reference</strong>
                    </h2>
                    <hr>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <img class="img-responsive img-border-left thumbnail" src="img/banner.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                  <ul class="list-unordered list-reference">
                    <li>Stavba budovy sociálního zařízení rekreačního areálu Kristýna, Hrádek nad Nisou</li>
                    <li>Rekonstrukce bytového domu, Horní Počernice</li>
                    <li>Stavba RD, Stráž pod Ralskem</li>
                    <li>Stavba RD, Vratislavice nad Nisou</li>
                    <li>Rekonstrukce RD, Proseč nad Nisou</li>
                    <li>Rekonstrukce RD, Rychnov u Jablonce nad Nisou</li>
                    <li>Oprava výrobní haly, Jablonné v Podještědí</li>
                    <li>Rekontrukce bytového domu, Česká Lípa</li>
                  </ul>

                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

            <div class="box">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                    <hr>
                    <div class="galerie">
                    <ul class="intro-text text-center">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#rekonstrukce" data-toggle="tab">Rekonstrukce</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#zemni_prace" data-toggle="tab">Zemní práce</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#rodinne_domy" data-toggle="tab">Rodinné domy</a></li>
                    </ul> 
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                  </div>
                </div>



            <div class="tab-content">

            <div class="tab-pane odstavec fade in active" id="rekonstrukce">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lightbox"> 
                      <img class="img-responsive" src="img/rekonstrukce/pic1.jpg" alt=""> 
                    </a>                  
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                  <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lightbox"> 
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/rekonstrukce/pic2.jpg" alt="">
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                  <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lightbox"> 
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/rekonstrukce/pic3.jpg" alt="">
                  </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                  <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lightbox"> 
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/rekonstrukce/pic4.jpg" alt="">
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                  <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lightbox"> 
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/rekonstrukce/pic5.jpg" alt="">
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                  <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lightbox"> 
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/rekonstrukce/pic6.jpg" alt="">
                  </a>
                </div>
            </div>  
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lightbox"> 
                      <img class="img-responsive" src="img/rekonstrukce/pic7.jpg" alt=""> 
                    </a>                  
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                  <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lightbox"> 
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/rekonstrukce/pic1.jpg" alt="">
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                  <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lightbox"> 
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/rekonstrukce/pic9.jpg" alt="">
                  </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lightbox"> 
                      <img class="img-responsive" src="img/rekonstrukce/pic10.jpg" alt=""> 
                    </a>                  
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                  <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lightbox"> 
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/rekonstrukce/pic11.jpg" alt="">
                  </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane odstavec fade" id="rodinne_domy">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lightbox"> 
                      <img class="img-responsive" src="img/rodinne_domy/pic1.jpg" alt=""> 
                    </a>                  
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                  <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lightbox"> 
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/rodinne_domy/pic2.jpg" alt="">
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                  <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lightbox"> 
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/rodinne_domy/pic3.jpg" alt="">
                  </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                  <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lightbox"> 
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/rodinne_domy/pic4.jpg" alt="">
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                  <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lightbox"> 
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/rodinne_domy/pic5.jpg" alt="">
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                  <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lightbox"> 
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/rodinne_domy/pic6.jpg" alt="">
                  </a>
                </div>
            </div>  
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                  <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lightbox"> 
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/rodinne_domy/pic7.jpg" alt="">
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                  <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lightbox"> 
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/rodinne_domy/pic8.jpg" alt="">
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                  <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lightbox"> 
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/rodinne_domy/pic9.jpg" alt="">
                  </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                  <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lightbox"> 
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/rodinne_domy/pic10.jpg" alt="">
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                  <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lightbox"> 
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/rodinne_domy/pic11.jpg" alt="">
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                  <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lightbox"> 
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/rodinne_domy/pic12.jpg" alt="">
                  </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                  <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lightbox"> 
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/rodinne_domy/pic13.jpg" alt="">
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                  <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lightbox"> 
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/rodinne_domy/pic14.jpg" alt="">
                  </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>  


            <div class="tab-pane odstavec fade" id="zemni_prace">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lightbox"> 
                      <img class="img-responsive" src="img/zemni_prace/pic1.jpg" alt=""> 
                    </a>                  
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                  <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lightbox"> 
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/zemni_prace/pic2.jpg" alt="">
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                  <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lightbox"> 
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/zemni_prace/pic3.jpg" alt="">
                  </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                  <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lightbox"> 
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/zemni_prace/pic4.jpg" alt="">
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                  <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lightbox"> 
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/zemni_prace/pic5.jpg" alt="">
                  </a>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
          </div>
        </div>
       </div> 





        <div id="lightbox" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
              <button type="button" class="close hidden" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <img src="" alt="" />
                    </div>
                </div>
          </div>  
        </div>


    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <p>Copyright &copy; www.mgstav.cz</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-lightbox.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is the webpage, so you could look at what it does: http://www.mgstav.cz/reference.html

- I noticed that the footer acts differently than on the other subpages too. I think that the container doesn't apply on the whole content, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "row" and "box" classes are reversed in this section of your code:

```
<div class="box"><!-- should be "row" -->
  <div class="row"><!-- should be "box" -->
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
      <hr>
      <div class="galerie">
        <ul class="intro-text text-center">
          <li class="active"><a href="#rekonstrukce" data-toggle="tab">Rekonstrukce</a></li>
          <li><a href="#zemni_prace" data-toggle="tab">Zemní práce</a></li>
          <li><a href="#rodinne_domy" data-toggle="tab">Rodinné domy</a></li>
        </ul> 
      </div>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the padding appearing below your home page footer (which is not applied on your sub pages) is coming from a rule in your 'bootstrap-lightbox.css' file:

```
body {
  padding: 30px 0px; /* applies top and bottom padding of 30px */
  overflow-y: auto !important;
}
```

**UPDATE: Padding Issue Fix When Modal Window Opens**

The easiest way to fix this issue is to override the inline styles I mentioned in the comments below. Add the following style rule to your 'business-casual.css' file:

```
body.modal-open,
.modal-open .modal {
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: That worked. I noticed another mistake though. When I click on any picture on the website, the lightbox moves the content of the webpage slightly. Do you know how to fix that, please? @trevor

Comment: When you click an image and the lightbox opens, an inline style is being applied to the <body> tag: <body class="modal-open" style="padding-right: 17px;">. Not sure where that is coming from, but it is the source of the problem.

Comment: So, you are not sure, how to fix that either? @trevor

Comment: The way to fix it is to remove the inline style. You'll need to look through your code to find and remove it. All I can tell you is that when you have a modal window open, the style affecting your webpage appears in two different places: in the body tag ( <body class="modal-open" style="padding-right: 17px;"> ), and in the lightbox modal html as well ( <div id="lightbox" class="modal fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block; padding-right: 17px;"> ). You'll need to look through your code to find the offending style.

Comment: Well, I wasn't able to find it, so I applied display: initial; on the body, is that correct? @trevor - probably not, now it moves down instead of left //EDITED

Comment: Don't apply display: initial. Do what I suggested in my edited answer above. Adding that style rule will fix your issue.